# Проверить есть ли на изображении пиксель с цветом 120, 255, 166

Tags: python, numpy, pil, cv2

У меня есть изображения и на некоторых есть пиксели с цветом 120, 255, 166. Мне нужно отобрать только изображения с такими пикселями.
Я пересмотрел много статей и видео про это и везде были варианты, либо перебирать циклом, либо с помощью numpy.where. Цикл мне не подходит по скорости, так как мне нужно определять это очень быстро, а numpy.where у меня не работает никаким образом.  Я пробовал вставлять в него numpy.all, numpy.any, пробовал просто numpy.any без numpy.where, но ни что не работает.
Есть ли простой вариант сделать это, например с помощью библиотек numpy, cv2 или хотя бы PIL?
Код который чаще всего встречался в статьях:

```
image = Image.open("image.png")  
numpy_array = numpy.array(image)  
check = numpy.where(numpy.any(numpy_array == [120, 255, 166]))
```

Comment: Ну, это так или иначе неизбежно приведёт к использованию цикла, вопрос сводится к тому, как этот цикл сделать быстрым

Comment: Покажите код, что у вас не получалось с numpy

Comment: И да, ещё очень важно знать способ получения картинки, потому что это тоже влияет на скорость

Comment: Способ получения картинки меня устраивает и на скорость не очень влияет. Я понимаю, что в любом решение будет циклом, но явно не простой for. Код добавил в вопрос.

Comment: По идее `numpy.where` тут лишнее, `numpy.any` уже должно быть достаточно. Но нужно смотреть, какая размерность у массива `numpy_array`, возможно нужны дополнительные параметры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант решения. Комментарии в коде

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

path = r"c:\test\image.png"  # https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/RGB_24bits_palette_R170.png
numpy_array = np.array(Image.open(path))
to_find = (170,2,2)
f = (numpy_array == to_find).all(axis=2) # условие поиска.  ищем по 2-й оси (0 - строки, 1 - столбцы, 2 - цвет), чтобы все три элемента цвета совпали
print(f'Цвет {to_find} в изображении `{path}` {"" if numpy_array[f].shape[0] > 0 else "НЕ "}найден.') # если вы выборке количество > 0, то цвет найден
```

```
Цвет (170, 2, 2) в изображении `c:\test\image.png` найден.
```

Для наглядности добавлен длинный вариант с разбором механики и тестированием способа на ложные срабатывания:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

path = r"c:\test\image.png"  # https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/RGB_24bits_palette_R170.png
numpy_array = np.array(Image.open(path))
numpy_array = numpy_array[:3,:3] # вырезаем 3*3 пиксела для наглядности
print("Исходный массив из 9 пикселов:")
print(numpy_array)
to_find = (170,2,2) # задаем цвет для поиска
numpy_array[0,0] = to_find[::-1] # для теста меняем первый пиксел на перевернутый искомый цвет, чтобы проверить ложные срабатывания
print("Модифицированный массив из 9 пикселов (в начало добавлен перевернутый цвет - те же значения компонент RGB, только задом наперед):")
print(numpy_array)
f = (numpy_array == to_find)
print("Булев массив поиска ([True  True  True] - только там, где надо):")
print(f)
print("Выборка поиска:")
print(numpy_array[f.all(axis=2)])
print("Результат:")
f = (numpy_array == to_find).all(axis=2) # условие поиска.  ищем по 2-й оси (0 - строки, 1 - столбцы, 2 - цвет), чтобы все три элемента цвета совпали
print(f'Цвет {to_find} в изображении `{path}` {"" if numpy_array[f].shape[0] > 0 else "НЕ "}найден.') # если вы выборке количество > 0, то цвет найден
```

```
Исходный массив из 9 пикселов:
[[[170   0   0]
  [170   0   1]
  [170   0   2]]

 [[170   1   0]
  [170   1   1]
  [170   1   2]]

 [[170   2   0]
  [170   2   1]
  [170   2   2]]]
Модифицированный массив из 9 пикселов (в начало добавлен перевернутый цвет - те же значения компонент RGB, только задом наперед):
[[[  2   2 170]
  [170   0   1]
  [170   0   2]]

 [[170   1   0]
  [170   1   1]
  [170   1   2]]

 [[170   2   0]
  [170   2   1]
  [170   2   2]]]
Булев массив поиска ([True  True  True] - только там, где надо):
[[[False  True False]
  [ True False False]
  [ True False  True]]

 [[ True False False]
  [ True False False]
  [ True False  True]]

 [[ True  True False]
  [ True  True False]
  [ True  True  True]]]
Выборка поиска:
[[170   2   2]]
Результат:
Цвет (170, 2, 2) в изображении `c:\test\image.png` найден.
```

Использовал [источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823608/find-matching-rows-in-2-dimensional-numpy-array)

Comment: Спасибо большое! И очень приятно, что есть подробный разбор работы кода.